# Cannot Evaluate Expressions while debugging in Netbeans 8.1 (PHP)

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I'm using the XDebug tool for my PHP files in Netbeans 8.1.  While debugging, the "Debug > Evaluate Expression" option is disabled. Does anyone know how to enable this?

I've already gone into "Tools > Options > PHP > Debugging" and checked "Watches and Balloon Evaluations".

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem, it seems like a bug, it is always disabled.

[image]

Comment: Same problem for me with NetBeans 11.0.

Comment: I issued a bug report against NetBeans 11.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2828